# How to fix the No bootable device on QEMU?

Tags: macos, windows-10, virtual-machine, qemu

I was trying to set up windows 10 insider version on my macbook pro 2014.
However, when I run
`qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom /Users/111/Downloads/Windows10_InsiderPreview_client_ARM64_en-us_21286.VHDX -m 2048M -hda Windows10.img`,
it shows that No more network devices, No bootable device.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWidM.jpg)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your qemu run with all the messages and errors.

Comment: ARM64 is wrong, you need the AMD64 version, also ask this on superuser.com

Comment: @nevilad added.

Comment: @magicandre1981 where can I get the AMD64 version? I'll ask this on superuser.com as well. Thank you.

Comment: That's the windows version for x64 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10.